# Failed to download namelesscoder/fluid from dist

Tags: composer-php, typo3, fluid, ddev, linter

I've tried to install this package:
https://github.com/TYPO3/Fluid.Lint

as a dev requirement via: ddev composer require typo3fluid/fluid-lint --dev

I am getting this error:

./composer.json has been updated
Loading composer repositories with package information                                                                                                                                                                                                            Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
Package operations: 1 install, 0 updates, 0 removals

- Installing namelesscoder/fluid (1.1.0): Downloading (failed)    Failed to download namelesscoder/fluid from dist: The "https://api.github.com/repos/NamelessCoder/TYPO3.Fluid/zipball/0b9a6b4d5d5096a470238fbccfb52beb257c7a71" file could not be downloaded (HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found)
  Now trying to download from source
- Installing namelesscoder/fluid (1.1.0): Cloning 0b9a6b4d5d

Installation failed, reverting ./composer.json to its original content.

[RuntimeException]
Failed to execute git clone --no-checkout 'https://***:***@github.com/NamelessCoder/TYPO3.Fluid.git.git' '/var/www/html/vendor/namelesscoder/fluid' && cd '/var/www/html/vendor/namelesscoder/fluid' && git remote add composer 'https://***:***@github.com/NamelessCoder/TYPO3.Fluid.git.git' && git fetch compose
r && git remote set-url origin 'https://github.com/NamelessCoder/TYPO3.Fluid.git.git' && git remote set-url composer 'https://github.com/NamelessCoder/TYPO3.Fluid.git.git'

Cloning into '/var/www/html/vendor/namelesscoder/fluid'...
remote: Repository not found.
fatal:***@github.com/NamelessCoder/TYPO3.Fluid.git.git/' not found

How can I fix this????????

Answer (score 0):

this is not an issue on your side. The repository link seems to have an incorrect second `.git` appended: `https://:@github.com/NamelessCoder/TYPO3.Fluid.git.git`.

Though this repository is not maintained since 5 years, this is possibly not up-to-date and working for current TYPO3 versions.

More see here: https://github.com/TYPO3/Fluid.Lint/issues/8

Comment: At the end of this link there is the same issue you have. If you watch this issue you get updates of the progress. One question mark is enough btw.

Answer (score 0):

There was never a new version released which uses the new package (see https://github.com/TYPO3/Fluid.Lint/commit/3c6e8fcefad1648c5c31dfdeebada99c03c7a0d7) so you have to require the dev-master instead:

```
ddev composer require typo3fluid/fluid-lint:dev-master --dev
```

Comment: Then I get this error:  [InvalidArgumentException]                                                     
  Could not find package typo3fluid/fluid-lint in a version matching dev-master

Comment: That's because you have to set minimum-stability to dev to allow dev versions in your project see https://getcomposer.org/doc/04-schema.md#minimum-stability